Apache httpclient5 - NoHttpResponseException: failed to respond
Sometimes the request failed with failed to respond
Caused by: org.apache.hc.core5.http.NoHttpResponseException: <host> failed to respond
    at org.apache.hc.core5.http.impl.io.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:301)
    at org.apache.hc.core5.http.impl.io.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:175)
    at org.apache.hc.core5.http.impl.io.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:218)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager$InternalConnectionEndpoint.execute(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:712)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalExecRuntime.execute(InternalExecRuntime.java:216)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:116)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ConnectExec.execute(ConnectExec.java:188)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:192)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.HttpRequestRetryExec.execute(HttpRequestRetryExec.java:96)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ContentCompressionExec.execute(ContentCompressionExec.java:152)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:115)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:170)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
    at org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.java:93)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:66)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:864)

